# delphi translation tool

Tags: delphi, localization, delphi-2009

I am looking for translation tools other than the features that come already with Delphi 2009.

I tried dxGetText, and the wischnewski.tv tool. I had problems setting them up.

Our need is for a tool to allow members of own software team to translate the strings in our software.

Could you suggest a component that does that, with example source code?

edit: We also tried the build in solutions of Delphi, and these did not meet our needs.

edit2: no end user translation is needed, only our translation team.

Comment: They all do that. You need to be more specific. See http://delphi.about.com/od/toppicks/tp/aatplocalize.htm

Comment: Also Delphi 2009 has a build in solution you could use.

Comment: @lars i read the list, and i am looking for recommendations, for good tools.

Comment: It is hard to find the right answer to this question since they pretty much all do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [Korzh Localizer](http://devtools.korzh.com/localization-delphi/) and I'm satisfied with this

but there is also :

[Tsilang](http://www.tsilang.com/)

[multilizer](http://www.multilizer.com/dev/vcl/)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Sisulizer](http://www.sisulizer.com/) and [Radialix](http://www.radialix.com/). These, along with [Korzch Localizer](http://devtools.korzh.com/localization-delphi/) will help you translate everything inside your app there is to be translated, resource strings, dialogs, delphi forms, etc. Solutions like Tsilang and DKLang unfortunately help translate only delphi forms. VCL for example stays English-only by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[TsiLang Components Suite](http://www.tsilang.com/index.html)**. It's very good.