# Catch a mouse click on any VCL component, and determine its .Tag value

Tags: delphi

I'm using a home-grown translation tool. (Next time I'll use one of the libraries, as described here: [delphi translation tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056098/delphi-translation-tool).)

My translators complain that translating a long list of strings is difficult because they're not seeing them in context (on the screen in which they appear.)

One translator made a great suggestion that he should be able to click on a component to change its text.  I can implement this **if** I can find an way to hook program wide, an event so that when a user clicks on a component while holding down the CTRL key, an event handler is called. The event handler would determine if the component has a .Caption property, and if so, get the value of the Tag component (and then allow some user input.)

(Each translatable component has unique integer in its Tag properly, which I use to look up the component's .Caption.)

Any suggestions on how to go about this?  It's over my head. I need something like a form's KeyPreview, but for mouse-clicks that would figure out what VCL component was clicked, and determine it's .Tag value.

Tom

EDIT:

Using David H.'s suggestion, the only events I get are when the app gets focus or loses it. What have I done wrong?

```
    function TForm1.AppHookFunc(var Message : TMessage) : Boolean;
    begin
      Result := FALSE;
      inc(i); outputdebugstring(Pchar(inttostr(i) + ': ' + IntTostr(Message.msg)));
      if Message.Msg = WM_MBUTTONDOWN then
        begin      Beep;
        //...DoSomething...
        //Result := True;
        end;
    end;

    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(  Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Application.HookMainWindow(AppHookFunc);
    end;

    procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(
      Sender: TObject);
    begin
      Application.UnHookMainWindow(AppHookFunc);
    end;
```

EDIT 2

I'm almost there!  But FindDragTarget seldom returns anything but nil. If I make an enormous button covering most of the control, I can sometimes get it to work.  The X,Y coordinates in the tagMSG received are relative to the control. I would have though they'd relative to the form.  Am I still using a different event hook than I should? Any suggestions:

```
  procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message( var Msg: tagMSG;
                                              var Handled: Boolean);
  var
    Target: TControl;
    Point: TPoint;
  begin
    Handled := FALSE;
    if (Msg.Message = WM_LBUTTONDOWN) And isAltDown then
      begin
        Point.X := LongRec(Msg.lParam).Lo;
        Point.Y := LongRec(Msg.lParam).Hi;
        Target := FindDragTarget( Point, {AllowDisabled=}TRUE);
        if Assigned(Target) then
          begin
            if Target Is TButton then
              outputdebugString(Pchar(TButton(Target).Caption));
          end
        else
          outputdebugstring(Pchar(IntToStr(Point.X) + ', ' + IntToStr(Point.Y)));
      end;
  end;
```

FINAL EDIT:

I changed the code above to use GetCursorPos rather than Msg.lParam.  It's working now. Very cool!  SO Rocks!

THANK YOU BOTH FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: If it would be enough for you to do the translations for `TWinControl` descendants then you might try to use [WindowFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to determine what control is under your mouse and get/set its text by `WM_GETTEXT` and `WM_SETTEXT` from outside of your application.

Comment: Don't hook the main window. Assign Application.OnMessage. Or use TApplicationEvents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a VCL app. For FireMonkey this would not work.

1. Add an `Application.OnMessage` event handler.
2. In the event handler look for `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` or perhaps `WM_LBUTTONUP` and check that the modifier key state is as you desire, e.g. CTRL is down.
3. Call [`FindDragTarget`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.FindDragTarget) passing the position associated with the mouse event. This will give you the control under the mouse, if indeed there is one (i.e. check for `nil`).
4. Do whatever it is you want to that control.

Comment: Supporting non-TWinControl controls is very easy, no need to switch to `TStaticText`. Use `FindDragTarget()` instead of `FindVCLWindow()`. `FindDragTarget()` calls `FindVCLWindow()` internally, then if found it calls that control's `ControlAtPos()` method to check for a non-TWinControl child.

Comment: @remy thanks. I'm a little indisposed right now. I'd be delighted for you to add that info as an edit or even a separate answer.

Comment: @remy I have become disposed once again and updated the question. Thanks for teaching me something I did not know. Again. I love SO!

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you, David.  How does one extract the keystate and x and y from the tagMSG?

Comment: I tend to be lazy and just call [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx). But it is included in the mouse message. In your case you test `wParam and MK_CONTROL=MK_CONTROL` to test for CTRL down. Note `MK_CONTROL=$0008`. You probably want to check that just CTRL is down by ensuring that the other modifiers are not down.

Comment: As for the position, again it is included in the message, in `lParam`. The low-order word specifies the x-coordinate of the cursor. The high-order word specifies the y-coordinate of the cursor. Use `LongRec(lParam).Lo` for the low-order word, i.e. x,  and `LongRec(lParam).Hi` for the high-order word, i.e. y.

Comment: One problem with this is that TApplicationEvents are not triggered for clicking on TMainMenu items, TabSheet headings, etc...

Comment: Unfortunately, `FindDragTarget` does not find disabled controls, even if `AllowDisabled` is set to `True` in Delphi 10.1 Berlin.