# Any way to detect if a form has been clicked?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, mouseclick-event, onmouseclick

Delphi XE

Is there any way to detect if a form has received a mouse click? The OnClick event in the form  is only triggered on empty parts of the form. Any parts which have controls won't respond.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not. Can you read the title and first paragraph, that has not changed, not a single letter. I made the error in adding the background which turned out to be irrelevant to the specific question being asked. Please revert my edits in order to make the question clear so that others are not inadvertently confused as you were when you gave an answer (to a different question). You answered a  question about OnActivate, I asked a question about OnClick.

Comment: Please read my question again. I confused you with the background, that was my fault. Just focus on the title and the first paragraph. That is THE question. You may have missed it but there is a question mark in the first sentence.

Comment: Any answer to the question? Would be interested in an answer. You have a very high reputation so you must know your material very well.

Comment: Why have you given my question a -1, it is perfectly sound question. How does one detect a mouse click on a form that is covered in controls? I am sorry if you were embarrassed by your mistake but that is no reason to downgrade the question.

Comment: Sorry. First you accuse me of not being able to read words that you wrote, then you ask for my help, then you accuse me of downvoting your question and think I did so because I'm embarrassed for answering the question you specifically asked in the first place? Right. First, voting here is anonymous, and unless someone specifically says they're downvoting, you shouldn't accuse them of doing so. Second, it's entirely possible that you were downvoted because your question was unclear (it's changed from what you asked). Third, poor idea to insult people you're asking for free help.

Comment: I'm sorry but you did misread the question but at the same time I admitted that it was caused by the addition of irrelevant background information on my part. I think you're taking this a bit too personally - I don't see any insult, you're reading between the lines.

Comment: No, I'm not. I have not once been condescending or insulting to you. I'm finished here. Once again, good luck.

Comment: Obviously I have said something that has very much upset you. I am sorry for that. I wish I knew what it was so as not to offend you in future.

Comment: This question was downgraded as lacking research and considered not useful. However I have a real problem to solve and was hoping the Delphi community might have an answer. According to you I can't change the current question (rightly so), therefore I did more research and rephrased the question to make it clearer and posted a new one, but I think you deleted it due to it being a duplicate. Please instruct me as to the correct way forward. Perhaps this one can be deleted and the new one reinstated?

Comment: I don't know why you keep accusing me of doing things. I cannot (and have not) deleted your question. You objected to my answer here because you edited the question, so I deleted my answer and reinstated the edit you made that I had reverted. I voted to close your new question as a duplicate of this one, because it is a duplicate of this one. It has not been deleted (or even closed, as of the time I'm writing this comment).

Comment: I am very sorry Ken, the question is still indeed there, my sincere apologies. I just discovered I can delete the second question, so I did so. Wish I had made the first question clearer, will know better next time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catch a mouse click on any VCL component, and determine its .Tag value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083445/catch-a-mouse-click-on-any-vcl-component-and-determine-its-tag-value)

Comment: If you are detecting form activation, use OnActivate. It does work. What you are trying to do is the wrong solution.

Comment: @KenWhite You got this one spot on, reading back the edit history. *"I am trying to figure out when a form gets focus."* And `OnActivate` is the correct way to do that. If rhody cannot make it work, then the correct approach is to fix whatever is wrong to make `OnActivate` work.

Comment: @David: Thanks. I was pretty sure I had (and wrote what I thought was a pretty clear answer, as you can see). Appreciate the agreement that I still have my reading skills. :-)

Comment: @whosrdaddy I found the 'catch a mouse...' before I created this question and I was hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: I have been trying to get OnActivate to work, I'll try again today. I agree it would be the ideal solution and it was the first thing I tried but after I couldn't get it to work (after some effort) I thought of detecting the form OnClick event which does work but it isn't a nice solution. I shouldn't have added the background to the question, that was a fatal mistake. I understand now that one should be very specific in a question and focus on one issue only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to filter queued messages to detect mouse events at a global level.

1. Add a handler for `TApplication.OnMessage`.
2. Listen to `WM_MOUSEDOWN` or `WM_MOUSEUP` as you please, and respond if the target window handle is that of the form, or a child control.
3. Make sure you leave the Handled parameter of the message as False so that the message is delivered to its target.

If you really are trying to detect form activation, use `OnActivate`.

Comment: I did try OnActivate but for what ever reason it only fires once. I should add that the Form resides in a DLL which may be complicating matters. Thank for the suggestion however, I'l give it a go.

Comment: OnActivate is the answer. We should just fix your code so that works.

Comment: For those who might be curious, I managed to get OnActivate working my moving the code to use packages. Excuse my ignorance if this is inappropriate to mention it here.

Comment: That's fine. We don't know what was wrong before because we don't know the organisation of your app. Packages make cross module code cleaner for sure.