# How to make TImage and TLabel receive WM_RBUTTONDOWN messages?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

In a Delphi 11 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10, at run-time, I right-click a control while holding down the SHIFT and CTRL modifier keys, to copy the name of the clicked control to the clipboard:

```
procedure TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  case Msg.message of
    Winapi.Messages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
      begin
        // Detect the name of the clicked control:
        var ThisControl: Vcl.Controls.TWinControl;
        ThisControl := Vcl.Controls.FindControl(Msg.hwnd);
        if Assigned(ThisControl) then
        begin
          var keys: TKeyboardState;
          GetKeyboardState(keys);
          // when right-clicking a control, hold down the SHIFT and CTRL key to escape the possible default click behavior of the control:
          if (keys[VK_SHIFT] and $80 <> 0) and (keys[VK_CONTROL] and $80 <> 0) then
          begin
            Handled := True;
            //CodeSite.Send('TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message: ThisControl.Name', ThisControl.Name);
            Vcl.Clipbrd.Clipboard.AsText := ThisControl.Name;
          end;
        end;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

This works with ALMOST all controls, EXCEPT with `Timage` and `TLabel` (and possibly a few other control types). How can I make this work with `Timage` and `TLabel` too?

Comment: `TLabel` does not have a handle. I don't believe that `TImage` does either. This means that you can't identify them by `Msg.hwnd`.

Comment: This is because `TImage` and `TLabel` are graphic controls (they derive from `TGraphicControl`) and not windowed controls (`TWinControl`). So a `TImage` (or a `TLabel`)  isn't a window in the Win32 sense -- it has no HWND. Instead, it merely paints itself on top of its parent, which *is* a windowed control.

Comment: Related/dupe: [Catch a mouse click on any VCL component, and determine its .Tag value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083445/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TImage` and `TLabel` are derived from `TGraphicControl`, not `TWinControl`. They do not have an `HWND` of their own, which is why `Vcl.Controls.FindControl()` does not work for them.  You are receiving `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` messages belonging to their `Parent`'s `HWND` instead.  Internally, when the VCL routes the message, it will account for graphical child controls.  But your code is not.

Try [`Vcl.Controls.FindDragTarget()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.FindDragTarget) instead.  It takes screen coordinates as input (which you can get by translating the client coordinates in `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`'s `lParam` using [`Winapi.ClientToScreen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clienttoscreen) or [`Winapi.MapWindowPoints()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapwindowpoints)), and then returns the `TControl` at those coordinates, so it works with both windowed and graphical controls.

That being said, you don't need to use `Winapi.GetKeyboardState()` in this situation, as `WM_RBUTTONDOWN`'s `wParam` tells you whether <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> keys were held down at the time the message was generated (remember, you are dealing with *queued* messages, so there is a delay between the time the message is generated and the time you receive it).

```pascal
procedure TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
const
  WantedFlags = MK_SHIFT or MK_CONTROL;
begin
  if Msg.message = WM_RBUTTONDOWN then
  begin
    // Detect the name of the clicked control:
    var Pt: TPoint := SmallPointToPoint(TSmallPoint(Msg.LParam));
    Windows.ClientToScreen(Msg.hwnd, Pt);
    var ThisControl: TControl := FindDragTarget(Pt, True);
    if Assigned(ThisControl) then
    begin
      // when right-clicking a control, hold down the SHIFT and CTRL key to escape the possible default click behavior of the control:
      if (Msg.wParam and WantedFlags) = WantedFlags then
      begin
        Handled := True;
        //CodeSite.Send('TformMain.ApplicationEvents1Message: ThisControl.Name', ThisControl.Name);
        Clipboard.AsText := ThisControl.Name;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I am not sure whether the expression `WantedFlags = WantedFlags` is equivalent to `12 = 12`? Maybe this expression `((Msg.wParam and WantedFlags) = WantedFlags)` adds clarity?

Comment: @user1580348: `and` [has higher precedence](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence) than `=`, so `Msg.wParam and WantedFlags = WantedFlags` is interpreted by the compiler as `(Msg.wParam and WantedFlags) = WantedFlags`: that is, the comparison checks that all the bits in `WantedFlags` are set in `Msg.wParam`. No need for parentheses, just like you don't need them in elementary school's `2 + 3×4`. So the expression `WantedFlags = WantedFlags` isn't part of Remy's code.

Comment: @user1580348 `and` has a higher precedence than `=`, so `Msg.wParam and WantedFlags = WantedFlags` would be interpreted as `(Msg.wParam and WantedFlags) = WantedFlags`, but OK, I've updated my example to make that more explicit.

Comment: In fact, the OP already knows this, since the OP's code contains `keys[VK_SHIFT] and $80 <> 0`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I love the clarity of EXPLICIT expressions! Implicit things sometimes lead to misunderstandings. I could tell you some real-life examples, but...

Comment: @user1580348 ...but then you would have used parentheses in your own code, right?

Comment: @AmigoJack How does your RHETORIC comment contribute to answering the current question? (Which is already answered).

Comment: @user1580348 It wasn't [rhetoric](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rhetoric) at all: why is your code the opposite of "clarity of explicit expressions" when you "love" it? And how does **your comment** contribute (other than underline your own inconsistency)?